# SpeechRecognizer can not hear me on some devices, the onRmsChanged() method is called only once

Tags: java, android, speech-recognition

I need some help solving a problem with SpeechRecognizer.

## Background

My task is to implement a voice memo feature: the user can record a short audio, save it, and then listen to it. If the user does not have the opportunity to listen to the audio, he can tap on the special "Aa" button and get a transcript of his voice note as text.

Since I did not find a suitable way to recognize prerecorded audio, I decided to implement speech recognition using SpeechRecognizer at the same time as recording audio. The recognition results are stored in a string, and when the user taps the "Aa" button, this string is displayed on the screen.

## Source

In the Activity, I declare a SpeechRecognizer and an Intent for it, as well as a string to store the recognized text, and a special variable isStoppedByUser. It is needed so that recognition stops only when the user himself stops recording (if the user pauses during speaking, recognition may stop automatically, but I do not need this).

```
private SpeechRecognizer speechRecognizer;
private Intent speechRecognizerIntent;

private String recognizedMessage = "";

private boolean isStoppedByUser = false;
```

I initialize the SpeechRecognizer in a separate method that is called from onCreate().

```
private void initSpeechRecognizer() {
    speechRecognizer = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(this);
    
    speechRecognizerIntent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    speechRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM); 
    speechRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS, 5); 
    speechRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE, getClass().getPackage().getName()); 
    speechRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.getDefault());

    boolean isRecognitionAvailable = SpeechRecognizer.isRecognitionAvailable(this);
    Toast.makeText(this, "isRecognitionAvailable = " + isRecognitionAvailable, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Log.i(TAG, "isRecognitionAvailable: " + isRecognitionAvailable);

    speechRecognizer.setRecognitionListener(new RecognitionListener() {
        
        @Override
        public void onRmsChanged(float rmsdB) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onRmsChanged() called with: rmsdB = [" + rmsdB + "]");
        }
        
        @Override
        public void onResults(Bundle results) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onResults() called with: results = [" + results + "]");

            ArrayList<String> data = results.getStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION);
            recognizedMessage += " " + data.get(0);
            Log.d(TAG, "onResults(): recognizedMessage = " + recognizedMessage);

            // If recognition stops by itself (as a result of a pause in speaking), we start recognition again
            if (!isStoppedByUser) {
                speechRecognizer.startListening(speechRecognizerIntent);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(int error) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onError() called with: error = [" + error + "]");

            if (!isStoppedByUser) {
                speechRecognizer.startListening(speechRecognizerIntent);
            }
        }

        // Other callback methods. They have nothing but logging
        // ... 
    });
}
```

The user starts recording:

```
startRecording();

isStoppedByUser = false;
recognizedMessage = "";
speechRecognizer.startListening(speechRecognizerIntent);
```

The user stops recording:

```
isStoppedByUser = true;
speechRecognizer.stopListening();

// Further processing of recorded audio
// ...
```

## Problem

I tested this functionality on two devices: Xiaomi 9T and Realme 8i.

Everything works fine on Xiaomi: as I speak, the `onRmsChanged()` method is called several times per second with different `rmsdB` values, I can clearly see this in the logs. That is, the sound level changes. Then other callback methods are called, and the string is successfully formed.

But on Realme, the `onRmsChanged()` method is called only once, at the very beginning, with a value of `-2.0`. Nothing else happens while I'm speaking, and when I stop recording, the `onError()` method is called with code 7 (`ERROR_NO_MATCH`).

It's as if the SpeechRecognizer can't hear me, but there are no problems with the microphone, and the `RECORD_AUDIO` permission is also granted: the audio itself is successfully recorded and can be listened to.

If I open the Google app and enter a voice request, everything also works fine.

I will be very grateful if you recommend what other parameters can be set to solve this problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be that it is impossible to use the microphone API for both recording and speech recognition at the same time. Therefore, the fact that everything works fine on Xiaomi turned out to be just a happy accident.